# emf vs eclipse-emf tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, synonym-request

These two tags describe the same usage:

- [eclipse-emf](/questions/tagged/eclipse-emf): 243 questions
- [emf](/questions/tagged/emf): 51 questions

(12 questions have [both tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emf+eclipse-emf))

So, it seems reasonable to combine these tags.

Therefore, I propose to **keep** [eclipse-emf](/questions/tagged/eclipse-emf) and to make the [emf](/questions/tagged/emf) tag a **synonym** of it because:

- [eclipse-emf](/questions/tagged/eclipse-emf) has (much) more questions it seems that users tend to find this tag more easily
- other eclipse frameworks use this scheme, see [eclipse-gmf](/questions/tagged/eclipse-gmf) or [eclipse-gef](/questions/tagged/eclipse-gef)

PS I am not allowed to propose this synonym in the regular way, because I do not have enough (any?) answers in [eclipse-emf](/questions/tagged/eclipse-emf)

Comment: At one time it would have made sense to have two distinct tags, but now combining them as suggested is the right thing to do.

Comment: There is in fact a third tag describing the same thing: [eclipse-emf-ecore]. Should synonymize that one with [eclipse-emf] as well, if there is no good reason to keep the specialization. (I don't see any.)